# Windows 10: Node-GYP error while installing npm/sharp

Tags: windows-10, node.js

I'm trying to [install](http://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/) an NPM package, [Sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp), but get the following error:

```
> sharp@0.21.3 install C:\Users\apixe\Documents\!X\Geola\node_modules\sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.7.0/libvips-8.7.0-win32-x64.tar.gz
ERR! sharp zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/page/install for required dependencies

C:\Users\apixe\Documents\!X\Geola\node_modules\sharp>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Users\apixe\Documents\!X\Geola\node_modules\sharp\build\libvips-cpp.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported proje
ct "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and th
at the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:135:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:224:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\apixe\Documents\!X\Geola\node_modules\sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v9.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.21.3 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.21.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\apixe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-12T22_07_00_879Z-debug.log
```

---

Here's the log at `C:\Users\apixe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-12T22_07_00_879Z-debug.log`: [Hastebin](https://hastebin.com/yamadataqa.sql)

---

OS: Windows 10, 64 bit

Node.JS: 9.0.0 (64 bit)

NPM: 5.5.1

Comment: For what it's worth. I had the same error message on Ubuntu 16 with node v4. Upgraded to node v11 and it worked.

Comment: @GijsjanB Interesting, for me, Node v11 breaks the core of my app, which my be related to the [library I work with](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js), not sure though